# Workaround for Azure AD B2C redirect limits

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Working with a client to create a new set of identity integrations using Azure AD B2C. All services are being developed around the identity platform, but one of the limitations we're running into is the max redirects with AAD B2C.

Client use case:

- third party software utilized for restaurant ordering
- client has approximately 700 restaurants
- after placing an order order for a particular restaurant from third party ordering system the user should be redirected back back to original restaurant
- URL structure would be something like [https://orderonline.company.com/[slug]](https://orderonline.company.com/%5Bslug%5D) - where [slug] would represent each of the 700 restaurants

Current understanding is a limit of 256 whitelisted URIs we can have for each B2C tenant, but we would need many more to make this solution work. Are there any workaround for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the `state` parameter when interacting with Azure AD / B2C in order to preserve information where exactly (which restaurant) should you redirect the end-user after authenticating.

The general documentation about Azure AD (relevant also to Azure AD B2C) is located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url).

More concrete about the approach is discussed in the section [Use a state parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#use-a-state-parameter).